# QGIS GeoTIFF layer styling - category labels

Tags: qgis, r, geotiff-tiff

I've created a raster object x in R, which is a categorical classification. I've used `levels(x) <- RAT` with a properly formatted raster attribute table to give the categories names, and then used writeRaster to export to GeoTIFF.

Running gdalinfo on the tiff, I can see the categories in the band information. Looks like:

```
Band 1 Block=799x5 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=1.000 Max=5.000
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=5.000, Mean=2.364, StdDev=2.147
  NoData Value=-9999
  Categories:
    0: 
    1: typeA
    2: typeB
    3: typeC
    4: typeD
    5: typeE
Metadata:
  STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5
  STATISTICS_MEAN=2.364214323665
  STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
  STATISTICS_STDDEV=2.1472654314354
```

So that's great, but QGIS can't seem to access that category info when I'm styling the layer. Is that even possible? They should act as legend labels.

Comment: It it still an open enhancement request in QGIS: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/22427

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although QGIS reads the category names, I don't think using them in symbology directly is currently possible.

For example (using python), I set some category names:

```
rb.SetCategoryNames(['a','b','c'])
```

GDAL shows the categories:

```
$ gdalinfo test.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
       test.tif.aux.xml
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
Band 1 Block=512x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Categories:
      0: a
      1: b
      2: c
```

In the QGIS layer properties, the category names show in the metadata section, but aren't available in the symbology section.

[image]

**However...**

If I set a Colour Table (again using python rather than r, but concept is the same):

```
ct=gdal.ColorTable()
ct.CreateColorRamp(0,(0,50,200),2,(0,255,200))
rb.SetCategoryNames(['a','b','c'])
rb.SetColorTable(ct)
```

I can see the category names in the symbology:

[image]

Note: I haven't tried getting rid of/not showing the unused colour table entries, I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Looks like you've replicated exactly what I did in Python, cool. I don't think setting categories either way we've tried counts as a true RAT though - ArcGIS can't use them in its Build Attribute Table tool.

Comment: Not *exactly*. I also set the colour table, which then uses the category names in the symbology and the legend which is what I thought you were trying to do.

Comment: @obrl_soil If you build a RAT (even just 2 columns, value and category) using GDAL, ArcGIS will use the entries in a unique values renderer by default. QGIS though can't read RATs at all, so you'd need to use a colour table like I suggest in my answer.

Comment: Looks like I'd have to move away from GeoTIFF to get support for RATs anyway.

Comment: @obrl_soil lack of RAT support is a QGIS issue not a geotiff issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do that by creating a virtual raster file (.vrt) in QGIS and editing it manually in any text editor.

All classes and colors will be interpreted from 0 on, thus I include NoData here as a hint to that.

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="109300" rasterYSize="89999">
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
  ...
    <ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
    <ColorTable>
      <Entry c1="255" c2="255" c3="255" c4="0"/>
      <Entry c1="204" c2="11" c3="30" c4="255"/>
      <Entry c1="187" c2="174" c3="108" c4="255"/>
      <Entry c1="21" c2="182" c3="103" c4="255"/>
      ...
    </ColorTable>
    <CategoryNames>
      <Category>NoData</Category>
      <Category>typeA</Category>
      <Category>typeB</Category>
      <Category>typeC</Category>
      ...
    </CategoryNames>
  ...
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

If you export this VRT to a new GeoTiff (`Right Click`-> `Export` ->  `Save As...`) you will end up with the colors encoded in the .tif and the classes in the associated .aux.xml